# Alternative way to write if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of shrinking my javascript code and I was wondering if there is a more elegan way to write this huge if statement:

```
if (operator_list == "=" || operator_list == "<>" || operator_list == ">" || operator_list == "<" || operator_list == ">=" || operator_list == "<=" )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Store the operators in an array, and check if `operator_list` exists in that array.

Comment: `indexOf` can be useful here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array and check if it includes `operator_list`

```
let checkArr = ["=", "<>", ">", "<", ">=", "<="];
if (checkArr.includes(operator_list)) {}
```

Comment: elegant solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could take a regular expression for it.

```js
function test(s) {
    return /^(=|<>|>|<|>=|<=)$/.test(s);
}

console.log(["=", "<>", ">", "<", ">=", "<=", 'foo', '<a='].map(test));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think refactoring the expression to a function and giving it a good name would make it more elegant:

```
if (isValidOperator(operator_list) ) {
 // Do something
}

function isValidOperator(operator) {
  return operator == "=" || operator == "<>" || operator == ">" || operator == "<" || operator == ">=" || operator == "<=";
}
```

This way you explain to the readers of your code what it is meant to do. In a later stage someone can refactor the function to make it easier to understand.

Other reads:

- Some other examples: https://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/01/27/refactoring-boolean-conditions-into-methods/
- [Clean Code book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the array of acceptable operators

```
var arr = [ "=", "<=" ];
```

then check if `operator` is one of the elements of the array

```
arr.indexOf( operator_list ) != -1 //will return true if operator_list is in arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an `if-test` consider an `in-array test`, as follows:

```js
var arrOps = ['=','<>','>','<','>=','<='];

var op = '=';

console.log ("Valid operator? ",   arrOps.indexOf(op) != -1);
```

The advantage of using the array's indexOf method is that it enjoys greater browser compatbility than the includes method; see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).